# Show that $\pi_1(SO(\infty))=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\pi_9(SO(\infty))=\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, topological-groups

We know

$$\pi_1(SO(\infty))=\pi_1(RP^3)=\mathbb{Z}_2$$

How to show
$$\pi_1(SO(\infty))=\mathbb{Z}_2?$$
and
$$\pi_9(SO(\infty))=\mathbb{Z}_2?$$

A related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/fundamental-group-of-so3).

Comment: You mean without using Bott periodicity?

Comment: Whatever argument you have is fine

Answer (score 2):

Bott periodicity implies that $\pi_k(O(\infty))=\pi_{k+8}(O(\infty))$.  From the perspective of homotopy groups, the difference between $O$ and $SO$ is negligible since $SO$ is a connected component of $O$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem