# Continuous function $ f：\operatorname{SO}(3) \to \operatorname{SU}(2)$

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Given the usual surjective homomorphism $ Φ:\operatorname{SU}(2)\to \operatorname{SO}(3)$ that maps a quaternion to a rotation matrix,

Does there exist a continuous function $f:\operatorname{SO}(3)\to \operatorname{SU}(2)$
such that $  \Phi \circ f = \operatorname{Id}$ on $\operatorname{SO}(3)$?

If yes, what would be this map be?

Thank you

Comment: No. It’s like trying to define a continuous square root in the complex plane. An element of SO(3) has an axis and an angle of rotation. The corresponding element of SU(2) has one half the angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A map $f$ as in your question would induce an embedding of fundamental groups $f_* :\pi_1(\text{SO(3)}) \to \pi_1(\text{SU}(2))$.

If you look at [Fundamental group of $SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200177), you will see that $\pi_1(\text{SU}(2)) = 0$, while $\pi_1(\text{SO(3)}) = \mathbb{Z}_2$. Therefore $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Frost

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof. It is known that $\Phi$ is a covering projection with two sheets. The map $f$ would be a section of $\Phi$, but this would imply that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism. See [If a covering map has a section, is it a $1$-fold cover?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256951).